# Linq join statement

Tags: linq

I am trying to select from multiple tables in an entity model. But there are two columns I would like to select and it's just not working out. The LINQ statement I have is:

```
var searchResult = from i in _imEntities.Issues
                   join dept in _imEntities.Departments
                   on i.Issued_to_dept equals dept.Dept_ID
                   where i.State == 1
                   select new {
                       i.ID_No,
                       i.Issue_Date,
                       Raised_By = dept.Dept_Name
                                       .Where(i.Raised_by_Dept == dept.Dept_ID),
                       Issued_To = dept.Dept_Name
                                       .Where(i.Issued_to_dept == dept.Dept_ID),
                       Details = i.Details
                   };
```

The column names are all correct, but I just can't get the dept_Names into the Raised_By and Issued_To fields. Is there another way to execute this?

Comment: When you say `I just can't get the dept_Names into the Raised_By and Issued_To fields`, do you mean you are receiving an exception, error or they are blank?

Comment: Originally the Issues table stores the dept_ID under Raised_By and Issued_To. Where Raised_By is the department that raises an issue and Issued_To is the department that the issue is "Issued To". I really want a query that joins the department and issue table and can show me the department name in a grid and not the dept_id.

Comment: When I say "I just can't get the dept_Names into the Raised_By and Issued_To fields", I mean that I can't get a logic using the linq query to show the corresponding department names for each department id stored under the respective fields...

Comment: I realize that you tagged your question with `linq`, but if you want a conceptual table that joins the department and issue table a view may suit you better than linq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query = from i in _imEntities.Issues
            join dept_r in _imEntities.Departments
            on i.Issued_to_dept equals dept_r.Dept_ID
            join dept_i in _imEntities.Departments
            on i.Issued_to_dept equals dept_i.Dept_ID
            where i.State == 1 
            select new {
                i.ID_No, 
                i.Issue_Date, 
                Raised_By = dept_r.Dept_Name,
                Issued_To = dept_i.Dept_Name, 
                Details = i.Details
            };
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much!! This is exactly what I was looking for. It's just that the dept_r was set to i.Issued_To but I changed it to i.Raised_By (minor stuff cuz I understood the query). U are  genius.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. But you definitely trying to apply *where* filter on single name string (also predicate syntax is not correct). Here is query which conditionally returns `Dept_Name` in `Raised_By` and `Issued_To` properties:

```
var query = from i in _imEntities.Issues
            join dept in _imEntities.Departments
            on i.Issued_to_dept equals dept.Dept_ID
            where i.State == 1 
            select new {
                i.ID_No, 
                i.Issue_Date, 
                Raised_By = (i.Raised_by_Dept == dept.Dept_ID) ? dept.Dept_Name : null,
                Issued_To = (i.Issued_to_dept == dept.Dept_ID) ? dept.Dept_Name : null, 
                Details = i.Details
            };
```

Comment: The query returns the Issued_To department names but not the Raised_By. The Raised_By is shown as null. i.Raised_by_Dept field is an int? (nullable int), could that be the cause of it?

Comment: @user2030579 yes, I'm selecting `null` if `Raised_by_Dept` of current issue not equal to `Dept_ID` of joined department.